# com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException:

Tags: json, regex, mongodb, mongodb-query, regex-group

I am getting this exception on the following code :

```
{ 'items.name' : {$regex:^"_param_0"$,$options:'i' }}
```

Method used is:

```
@Query("{ 'items.name' : {$regex:^?0$,$options:'i' }}")
public List<MenuEntity> getMenuByitemNameExact(String name);
```

Answer (score -1):

Modify method as below.

```
@Query(value = "{'items.name': {$regex : ?0, $options: 'i'}}")
List<MenuEntity> findByitemNameRegex(String name);
```